# Inconsistent results beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So, I'm scraping a website and while I am able to return the webpage's html the beautiful "find" results are inconsistent. 
While running retrieving the same page over and over, BS4 can sometimes find a certain tag and sometimes it cannot.

I tested the webpage len and when Beautiful soup was able to retrieve wanted tags , the len was 9220189 (correct size), and when it couldn't, 103557968.
I printed the webpage on both sizes and they are consistent. In fact, the string I am looking for can be found in both webpage prints.

Could this be a size limitation of beautiful soup?
I'm not sure what's going on?

EDIT:
link:
https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/ligand.php?brenda_ligand_id=1

what I am looking for:
soup.find(string='Molecular Formula')

The string can sometimes be found, sometimes it cannot. The text is in the webpage always and is not being loaded with javascript.

Comment: Is it possible that the website you are scraping may render different views per visit? Could be a login page popping up or something like that. Happened to me before when I was trying to scrape a page repeatedly.

Comment: Please add the url and code which is causing the err so that we can help! Also it's possible that you might be scraping dynamic site/js rich site so that it's causing inconsistency.

Comment: @CSMaverick done, link and soup.find added

Comment: @VictorWong I don't think it's rendering different views.

Comment: Do you want to iterate over id? https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/ligand.php?brenda_ligand_id=1 , Bcuz all I can find 1 element H2O with Ctrl+F

Comment: @CSMaverick I can but that's not the idea. I want to retrieve the info from specific IDs but sometimes I cannot due to this inconsistent behavior. Example added to post

Comment: So you want to get Molecular Formula which is H2O that is it?? just tell us what all you need to extract from the web page you've mentioned. it doesn't matter change in lenght of webpage. as long as you get all your data out of it.

Comment: @CSMaverick in this case, yes. Not always though. I tested reducing webpage length to 30000 characters and beautiful soup was able to retrieve all data. So I'm pretty sure it's a problem with the way beautiful soup handles large files.

Comment: Please add your code to your question so we can recreate the issue directly.

Comment: You are getting two different page sizes, but you say that the contents are the same? That makes no sense. You made a mistake. There have to be two different contents.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by reducing the size of the html. While I don't find a better solution, this will have to do.